# Exception While running testng.xml with Maven

Tags: maven, testng

pom.xml file Structure as given on attached Screen,
[image]While Running Maven Test, I got the below error,

```
Running TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.631s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 18 00:20:38 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/108M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project FirstDemo: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: com.google.tests.GoogleHomePageTest
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:544)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown
```

testng.xml is

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Example test run">
  <test name="Simple Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.google.tests.GoogleHomePageTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

How can I resolve this exception ??Help is really appreciated. ThankS in Advance....

Comment: Well. Is the class `com.google.tests.GoogleHomePageTest` in the classpath? If so, where is it coming from? A dependency? Your own project?

Comment: yes this is the classpath where my test resides, 'com.google.tests.GoogleHomePageTest' . Its on my Local(own Project).

Comment: @SacTan I too facing the same problem. if you found/resolved the issue can you please post it as answer. It may helpful for others who are facing the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Manigandan, I have changed the build path, it was previously point to 1.5, I changed that to 1.7 and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like class path issue, you can try by specifying the scope like this

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

and also there is no xml version in testng.xml file, off-course it may not cause but generally i will use it also

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score -1):

It's looks like,

maven is not able to find out the:
Cannot find class in classpath: com.google.tests.GoogleHomePageTest

It means target folder did not have .class files.
Please verify the .class file into the target folder if it is not present then delete the target folder and re-run the pom again, then check if it still not available then problem is with you structure which would not be compatible with maven. verify that maven is compiling your code or not if not then mention below lines in POM.xml

`<build>
<sourceDirectory>NameOfYourSourceDirectory</sourceDirectory>
</build>`

Then you will get the .class files in the target folder and now you can run your code using surefire plugin.